# How to select only the first line from an raw in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

could somebody know how i can display with echo only the first line from the raw?  Code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM articol 
                       WHERE id = '$artid'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($coloana = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $continut = $coloana["continut"];
}

<?php echo $continut; ?>
```

...and its echo me all the field, and i want only first line, or only 180 characters.

Comment: i want to use it for meta description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
substring(field_name,1,180) as begin_text,
other_fields_list 
from articol where id = '$artid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the keyword 'LIMIT' ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(continut, 1, 180), '\n', 1) AS part FROM articol WHERE id = '$artid'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // $continut = $row["part"];
    print $row["part"];
}
```

Comment: it's working but is printing an new line and because of that is echo'ing me an "> before the template begins, now i'm trying to remove the \n